# Excel VBA - Comma Separated Cells to Rows

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me with some advice regarding the below excel. In the incipient form looks like this:

```
A   B    C
1   A1  ;100;200;300;400;500;
2   A2  ;716;721;428;1162;2183;433;434;1242;717;718;
3   A3  ;100;101;
```

And i want to reach this result:

```
A    B     C
1   A1  100
1           200
1       300
1       400
1       500
2   A2  716
2       721
2       428
2       1162
2       2183
2       433
2       434
2       1242
2       717
2       718
3   A3  100
3       101
```

I tried using this code, but it does not return the expected result.

```
Sub SliceNDice()
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
 'Define the range to be analysed
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
     'Split each string by ";"
    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ";")
    For Each strArr In tempArr
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
         'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
    Next
Next lngRow
 'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[c1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should format your code so that its readable. When editing, you can see the {}. Highlight your code and apply it so its readable to everyone.

Comment: It's my first question. I'll bear this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Only column A and C.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomething()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim srcwsh As Worksheet, dstwsh As Worksheet
Dim sTmp As String, sNumbers() As String

Set srcwsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dstwsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

i = 1
j = 1
Do While srcwsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
    sTmp = srcwsh.Range("C" & i)
    sNumbers = GetNumbers(sTmp)
    For k = LBound(sNumbers()) To UBound(sNumbers())
        dstwsh.Range("A" & j) = srcwsh.Range("A" & i)
        dstwsh.Range("B" & j) = srcwsh.Range("B" & i)
        dstwsh.Range("C" & j) = sNumbers(k)
        j = j + 1
    Next
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set srcwsh = Nothing
Set dstwsh = Nothing


End Sub

Function GetNumbers(ByVal sNumbers As String) As String()
Dim sTmp As String

sTmp = sNumbers
'remove first ;
sTmp = Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1)
'remove last ;)
sTmp = Right(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1)

GetNumbers = Split(sTmp, ";")

End Function
```

Note: i'd suggest to add error handler. For further information, please see: [Exception and Error Handling in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6da8809%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @user3016842, believe me, it does what it have to do. Please, check the names of source and destination sheets.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you

```
Sub SplitAndCopy()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourTargetSheet")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    k = 2
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = LBound(Split(Range("C" & i).Value, ";")) + 1 To UBound(Split(Range("C" & i).Value, ";")) - 1
            sh.Range("A" & k).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            If j = LBound(Split(Range("C" & i).Value, ";")) + 1 Then
               sh.Range("B" & k).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
            End If
            sh.Range("C" & k).Value = Split(Range("C" & i).Value, ";")(j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: One of good programming practice says: if some piece of code is used more than one, move it into separate function/subroutine. ;) Above code does what it have to do, but the result of Split function should be "saved" into variable. This is the only reason i abstain from upvoting your answer.

Comment: I am sorry that I have disappointed you with my programing practices lol

Comment: I'm receiving a error message for this script at line Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourTargetSheet"). Run time error '9' - Script out of range.

Comment: That is likely because your activesheet name is not "YourTargetSheet" :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go this way:

```
Private Type data
   col1 As Integer
   col2 As String
   col3 As String
End Type

Sub SplitAndCopy()

   Dim x%, y%, c%
   Dim arrData() As data
   Dim splitCol() As String

   ReDim arrData(1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))

   x = 1: y = 1: c = 1

   Do Until Cells(x, 1) = ""
       arrData(x).col1 = Cells(x, 1)
       arrData(x).col2 = Cells(x, 2)
       arrData(x).col3 = Cells(x, 3)

       x = x + 1
    Loop

    [a:d].Clear

    For x = 1 To UBound(arrData)

        Cells(c, 2) = arrData(x).col2
        splitCol = Split(Mid(arrData(x).col3, 2, Len(arrData(x).col3) - 2), ";")

        ' sort splitCol

        For y = 0 To UBound(splitCol)
            Cells(c, 1) = arrData(x).col1
            Cells(c, 3) = splitCol(y)
            c = c + 1
        Next y

    Next x

End Sub
```

I am not totally sure if you need your third column sorted, in case you can add a sorting function.

Comment: Good, you can flag it as 'answer' then :)